# How can you run instrumentation tests from android studio to firebase with orchestrator?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso, firebase-test-lab

I'm trying to run ui android instrumentation tests from android studio to firebase using android studio user interface.

I tried using the terminal and all works fine, after setting up orchestrator dependencies and using ./gradlew connectedCheck command  test apk will be generated. After uploading it to firebase lab tests manually, results are ok. But when i run tests using gui, i get some weird errors like

java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not launch intent Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.project.ui/.MainActivity } within 45 seconds.

Or

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.project.ui.StartUp.getString(int)' on a null object reference

Am i getting these errors because these tests run without orchestrator?[Test configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIFLM.png)